# How do I 'correctly' connect this mic to that wireless system

Tags: microphone, cable

I have a Rode NTG2 mic and a Rodelink Wireless Filmmaker kit.

I don't know how to correctly connect one to the other.
I know I need an XLR female to 3.5mm TRS male cable.
I've tried two cable configurations (see pics below)

[image: This gives a very weak tinny signal with lots of noise]
This gives a very weak tinny signal with lots of noise

[image: This gives a much stronger signal but has an annoying hum]
This gives a much stronger signal but has an annoying hum

Can someone please explain to me where I'm going wrong and what I need to do to get it sounding the way it should sound?

Comment: The hum was tracked to the wireless system signal. The closer the mic was to the transmitter/receiver the greater the hum.
Increasing the distance seems to have solved the issue.

Comment: Toni - that isn't actually an answer. In your second configuration, you expect hum, as the signal is unbalanced. The first configuration can be used as a balanced config (which removes hum) but you need a balanced cable etc (as per K.Tzortis' comment)

Answer (score 1):

use a connection as shown in the first pic and put a AA battery in the microphone.it needs power to operate properly.

Comment: I tried using a connection as shown in the first pic with a battery in the mic and the result was a very weak signal with lots of noise.

Comment: I have made a comparison video to demonstrate the problem.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bOSrU5MiDsk

Comment: it's sound like you have close circuit between pin 2 and 3 somewhere. note that the output of the receiver is two unbalance channels. that means you need also a special cable to separate them.